# Dealing with resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Window xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:DM.Properties"
    xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
    xmlns:igWindows="http://infragistics.com/Windows"
    xmlns:igPrim="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml/primitives"
    xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:DM.Properties"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    x:Class="DM.PageEightInThree"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    FontFamily="B Mitra"
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    Title="Dummies Maker" Height="500" Width="1000" Background="#FF181818">
<Grid Margin="10">

    <telerik:RadCarousel x:Name="carsoul" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Height="422" />
    <Button Width="173" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" TabIndex="0" Content="اضافه کردن آیکون جدید" Height="26" Margin="609,0,190,10" />
    <Button Width="173" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click_1" TabIndex="1" Content="حذف آیکون" Height="26" Margin="410,0,389,10" />
    <Button Width="173" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click_2" TabIndex="2" Content="بازگشت" Height="26" Margin="212,0,587,10" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.823,0.346" />

</Grid>
```

And its code behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Telerik.Windows.Data;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation;
using DM.Properties;

namespace DM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PageEightInThree.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PageEightInThree : Window
    {
        internal static String pathOfIcons = @"Icons";
        internal static String txtFile = "Location.txt";
        public PageEightInThree()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Init();
            this.carsoul.ItemsSource = IconImagesForDummiesService.GetImages();
            this.carsoul.Focus();
        }
    private void Init()
    {
        List<String> res = new List<string>(50);
        String[] names = Directory.GetFiles(PageEightInThree.pathOfIcons, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var items = names.Where(a => !a.Contains(txtFile));
        foreach (var inner in items)
        {
            res.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(inner));
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(pathOfIcons + @"/" + txtFile, res, Encoding.Unicode);
    }
}
public class IconImagesForDummies
{
    private String name;
    private Image image;
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }
    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return this.image;
        }
        set
        {
            this.image = value;
        }
    }
}
public class IconImagesForDummiesService
{
    public static List<Image> GetImages()
    {
        String path = PageEightInThree.pathOfIcons + @"/" + PageEightInThree.txtFile;
        String path2 = PageEightInThree.pathOfIcons;
        List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        ObservableCollection<IconImagesForDummies> icons = new ObservableCollection<IconImagesForDummies>();
        String[] lines = null;
        if (File.Exists(path))
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Unicode);
        if (lines != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
            {
                String str = path2 + "/" + lines[i];
                if (File.Exists(str))
                {
                    Image im = new Image();
                    im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(str, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    im.Height = 200;
                    im.Width = 200;
                    images.Add(im);
                    icons.Add(new IconImagesForDummies() { Name = str, Image = im });
                }
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("The Location.txt which stores the location of icons is missing");
        if (icons.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("There is no icon image");

        List<Image> res = new List<Image>();
        for (int i = 0; i < icons.Count; ++i)
            res.Add(icons[i].Image);

        return res;
    }
}
```

I am using a text file named `Location` which holds the name of all images in icon folder. I make a list of images then pass it to the `WPF` control to show the images. There is a folder named Icon, It contains Images with `Build Action` which is set to `Copy Always`. At first the program works properly and all images in icon folder are shown properly, but after two or three times of rerunning the program, the images are not show, Why is that?

Comment: Couldn't you just add them as resources in the project?

Comment: actually I have too many images and I can not put them in resource folder.

Comment: How do you run it in that two or three times.

Comment: @Versatile all are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of struggling I found that the Location should have absolute value as its address. I do not know the reason but I achieved the mentioned desire by using `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`. But still do not know why the Image class needs absolute address.